# Combining awk statements

Tags: awk

I'd like to combine those awk statements:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF>1 && $NF!=""' #prints every row with more than two fields 
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/'        #prints every row starting with a number 
awk -F'\t' 'NF==1'           #prints every row with one only field
awk '$1 ~ /^[A-Z]/'        #prints every row starting with a capital letter
```

in order to get a statement printing every row that begins with a capital letter AND contains one only field, and every row with more than two fields, each of them starting with an integer.

Sample input:

```
NAME_1
1   
11  11
key 11
KEY KEY
```

Expected output:

```
NAME_1
11  11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them using `awk` logical `&&` and `||` (See more [awk boolean operators](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html)):

```
$ awk '(NF > 1 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]/) || (NF == 1 && $1 ~ /^[[:upper:]]/)' file
NAME_1
11  11
```

You should use `[[:upper:]]` to match capital letter because `[A-Z]` only work in C locale.

Comment: What if I would like to pick the corresponding line only if *each* field (of the line starting with an integer) start with an integer?

Comment: Use a `for` loop over all the fields, if a field does not start with an integer, skip to next input, otherwise print. Something like `(NF > 1 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]/) {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){...}}`